# Read csv file from sftp location via Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am using below command to read a csv file from Windows location

```
Import-Csv "D:\Test1.csv"
```

I then do some operations on CSV and put it back to the same location

```
$pqr > "D:\Test2.csv"
```

Any way to import the CSV file from SFTP location and dump it back to the same location via PowerShell?

Comment: Unless you can mount that SFTP site as a `PSDrive`, you'll need to download the file first, perform your manipulations, then upload it.

Answer (score 2):

The [Posh-SSH](https://github.com/darkoperator/Posh-SSH) module makes it quite trivial to download and upload files to SFTP:

```
$Credentials = Get-Credential
$Session = New-SFTPSession -ComputerName "mySFTPserver" -Credential $Credentials

# Get /path/to/file.txt and save to C:\folder\file.txt
Get-SFTPFile -SFTPSession $Session -RemoteFile "/path/to/file.txt" -LocalPath "C:\folder\"

## your code to modify file

Set-SFTPFile -SFTPSession $Session -LocalFile "C:\folder\file.txt" -RemotePath "/path/to"
```

Or you can just get the content of the file without downloading it:

```
$Credentials = Get-Credential
$Session = New-SFTPSession -ComputerName "mySFTPserver" -Credential $Credentials

$file_content = Get-SFTPContent -SFTPSession $Session -Path "/path/to/file.txt"

## your code to modify $file_content

Set-SFTPContent -SFTPSession $Session -Path "/path/to/file.txt" -Value $file_content
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use [WinScp](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell#example) to download and upload your file.